# scanf do not work fine with qword in assembly

Tags: assembly, scanf, 64-bit, x86-64, nasm

I made a little 64 bits NASM assembly program in Ubuntu to test scanf C function but is do not work properly if the destination field is a qword.

```
global  main
extern  printf
extern  scanf
section         .data
    msgInNum        db  'Type a number: ',0
    numFormat       db  '%d',0
    msgOuNum        db  'Your input %d ',10,0
    number          dq  0
section         .bss
section         .text
main:
    push rbp
other:
    mov     rdi,msgInNum
    xor     rax,rax
    call    printf

    mov     rdi,numFormat
    mov     rsi,number
    mov     al,0
    call    scanf

    mov     rdi,msgOuNum
    mov     rsi,[number]
    xor     rax,rax
    call    printf

    cmp     qword[number],0
    jge     other

    pop rbp
    ret
```

The problem is that the program never ends due the cmp instruction never finds into number a negative value when I type, for example -1 for the scanf.
But the thing is that if I change the definition of number as dw instead of dq (and the same in cmp changing qword by dword) the program works fine!

Below the commands to assemble, linking and execute:

```
nasm test.asm -f elf64
gcc test.o -no-pie
./a.out
```

Comment: Note for future reference that a 32-bit dword is declared with `dd`, not `dw` which is for a 16-bit word.

Comment: You are right, dd is the correct way.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling scanf with a %d, which corresponds to a pointer to an int.   An int is typically a 32bit (dword) not 64bit (qword).   Change numFormat to be '%ld', and it works as you expect.

Comment: (Or on Windows, `%lld` since only `long long` is a 64-bit type there, unlike on Linux/Mac.  In case future readers have a similar bug on a different OS.)